# Vue warn]: Property "isMobileTerminal" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm working on a project that's both mobile and PC，I need to estimate the mobile terminal or PC terminal。
flexible.js

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { PC_DEVICE_WIDTH } from '../constants'
import { useWindowSize } from '@vueuse/core/index'

const { width } = useWindowSize()

// 判断当前是否为移动设备，判断依据屏幕宽度是否小于一个指定宽度（1280）
export const isMobileTerminal = computed(() => {
  return width.value < PC_DEVICE_WIDTH
})
```

and the navigation/index.vue code is

```html
<template>
  <mobile-navigation v-if="isMobileTerminal"></mobile-navigation>
</template>

<script>
import { isMobileTerminal } from '../../../../utils/flexible'
import mobileNavigation from './mobile/index.vue'
export default {
  name: 'index',
  components: {
    mobileNavigation
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

My project catalog is shown below
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`isMobileTerminal` is only imported in your component. It also needs to be made available to the template by declaring it in your component definition.

Returning it from the [`setup()` hook](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html) is one way to do that:

```html
<script>
import { isMobileTerminal } from '../../../../utils/flexible'

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      isMobileTerminal
    }
  }
}
</script>
```